# i want pass the object value to find query it log properly but not passed empty i dont understand the reason , how to fix this

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mongodb-query

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";


const newSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    end_year: String,
    intensity: Number,
    sector: String,
    topic : String,
    insight : String,
    url : String,
    region: String,
    start_year : String,
    impact :String,
    added : String,
    published : String,
    country :String,
    relevance : Number,
    pestle:String,
    source : String,
    title : String,
    likelihood : Number

})

const item = mongoose.model("item",newSchema)

export default item;
```

```
import item from "../FilterSchema/filterschema.js";


export const AddFilter = (req, res) => {
    
    
     let filter_body = req.body;
     console.log("Filter conditions:", filter_body);  
     findData(filter_body,res)
}

export const findData = async (filter_body, res) => {    
    try {
        const query = {};
        

        if (filter_body.topic) {
            query.topic = filter_body.topic;

        }
        if (filter_body.end_year) {
            query.end_year = filter_body.end_year;
        }
        if (filter_body.sector) {
            query.sector = filter_body.sector;
        }
        if (filter_body.region) {
            query.region = filter_body.region;
        }
        if (filter_body.pestle) {
            query.pestle = filter_body.pestle;
        }
        if (filter_body.source) {
            query.source = filter_body.source;
        }
        if (filter_body.country) {
            query.country = filter_body.country;
        }
        if (filter_body.insight) {
            query.insight = filter_body.insight;
        }
        
        console.log(query.topic); 

        const Items = await item.find(query);
        res.status(200).json(Items);
        console.log(query);
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("There is a problem at findData", error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
    }
}
```

`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSHcD.png)

hi guys this is the code block i  have been stuck on ok the objective is i want to make a filter from and based on input the query will return maching data the problem is this sector properly log but dont pass to find query thats why it returns all data. i want filtered data, i want to query all field at once can any one help me to upgrade the code , another note many of data field value are emty  string.